# How get start date & end date for shifts from list of elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, date

simply what I want if `shift == D` then I want start date and end date of D, for example in first how many times D appear it 4 times so `start date =2021-04-01` and `end date = 2021-04-04` that's it same to N also from when N start and end I want just start date, end date and create new dictionary for `shift_type` leave W but count it also for proper date's I don't understand how do it please check the output that I mentioned

```py
shift_lst = ["D","D","D","D","N","N","W","N","N","D","D","D","D","W","N","N","N"]
current_date = date(2021, 4, 1)
shift_dict=dict()
for shift in (shift_lst):
    if shift == "D":
        shift_type='S1'
        enddate = current_date + timedelta(days=1)
    elif shift == "W":
        enddate = current_date + timedelta(weeks=1)
    elif shift == "N":
        shift_type='S2'
        enddate = current_date


end_date = current_date
shift_dict['shift_type']=shift_type
shift_dict['start_date']=current_date
shift_dict['end_date']=enddate
```

Expected Output:

```
{'shift_type' : 'S1','start_date':'2021,4,1','end_date':'2021,4,4'},
{'shift_type' : 'S2','start_date':'2021,4,5','end_date':'2021,4,9'},
{'shift_type' : 'S1','start_date':'2021,4,11','end_date':'2021,4,13'}
```

Comment: first of all, take the `shift_dict=dict()` outside of the loop...

Comment: @D.L please solve this problem sir

Comment: @SagarPatil what does N and W do, how did you get the 3rd entry in your output?

Comment: @Jay N stands for Night shift and W stands for Weekend D stands for Day shift

Comment: when D start then get the start date when it end get end date, also with N when it start after D so find the D's end date it becomes N start date then count it get its enddate until D coming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need to approach the problem like this:

1. create an empty `list` to store the `dicts` (a list of dicts).
2. check each element vs the previous (to identify a change).
3. modify the dicts accordingly.

So the code could look like this:

```py
import datetime as dt

shift_lst = ["D","D","D","D","N","N","W","N","N","D","D","D","D","W","N","N","N"]
current_date = dt.date(2021, 4, 1)

list_of_shifts = []

# firt element
if shift_lst[0] == 'D': shift_type = 'S1'
if shift_lst[0] == 'N': shift_type = 'S2'

shift_dict = {'shift_type':shift_type, 'start_date':current_date, 'end_date':current_date}

for i in range(1, len(shift_lst)):

    # check if the shift has changed
    if shift_lst[i] != shift_lst[i-1]:
        # and not a weekend
        if shift_lst[i] == "W":
            pass
        else:
            list_of_shifts.append(shift_dict)
            # start a new dict
            shift_dict={'shift_type':shift_type, 'start_date':current_date, 'end_date':current_date}
    
    if shift_lst[i] == 'D':
        shift_type='S1'
        current_date = current_date + dt.timedelta(days=1)
    elif shift_lst[i] == "W":
        current_date = current_date + dt.timedelta(weeks=1) 
    elif shift_lst[i] == "N":
        shift_type='S2'
        current_date = current_date
    shift_dict["end_date"] = current_date


for i in list_of_shifts:
    print(i)
```

And the result would be this:

```
{'shift_type': 'S1', 'start_date': datetime.date(2021, 4, 1), 'end_date': datetime.date(2021, 4, 4)}
{'shift_type': 'S1', 'start_date': datetime.date(2021, 4, 4), 'end_date': datetime.date(2021, 4, 11)}
{'shift_type': 'S2', 'start_date': datetime.date(2021, 4, 11), 'end_date': datetime.date(2021, 4, 11)}
{'shift_type': 'S2', 'start_date': datetime.date(2021, 4, 11), 'end_date': datetime.date(2021, 4, 22)}
```

You can customise the above to suit your needs...

Comment: Thanks at least it gives output like that thank you so much @D.L

Comment: You are welcome.  If it is helpful, please accept the answer so that other users can share the benefit.

Comment: did you understand my question what i want to say if not please ask again i'll tell you

Comment: Your question text could have been improved. Fortunately, **your attempt at the code was very helpful** in understanding the problem and producing the answer which is why stack encourages posting the attempt...

Comment: But I get error when I get another list please look ones below

Comment: what error do you get ?  i have tried the code on a number of variations and it works as expected.  Can you show a list or example which fails and what the failure is please ?

Comment: `name 'shift_type' is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

What if I got "W" first randomly or "L" first (L stands for leave) now see in List `shift_lst` I got "W" first so leave the "W" or "L" (if L got first) and start from "D" until "N" not come, get start date and end date of "D" like this `start_date=2021,4,2 & end_date=2021,4,4` after "D" with "N" when it start on 10th so start_date = 2021,4,10 and end_date = 2021,4,21 so after `2021,4,21` leave "W" and get D Start And end date

- `D shift_type = "S1"`
- `N shift_type = "S2"`

```
    import datetime as dt
    shift_lst = [ "W","D","D","D","L","L","L","L","L","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","W","D","D","D","D","D","D","W","D"]
    current_date = dt.date(2021, 4, 1)

    list_of_shifts = []
    shift_type=None

    # firt element
    if shift_lst[0] == 'D': shift_type = 'S1'
    if shift_lst[0] == 'N': shift_type = 'S2'

    for i in range(1, len(shift_lst)):

        # check if the shift has changed
    
        if shift_lst[i] != shift_lst[i - 1]:
        # and not a weekend
        if shift_lst[i] == "W":
            pass
        else:
          
            # start a new dict
            list_of_shifts.append(shift_dict)
            shift_dict = {
                'shift_type': shift_type,
                'start_date': current_date,
                'end_date': current_date
            }
          

        if shift_lst[i] == 'D':
            shift_type = 'S1'
            current_date = current_date + dt.timedelta(days=1)
        elif shift_lst[i] == "W":
            current_date = current_date + dt.timedelta(days=1)
        elif shift_lst[i] == "N":
            shift_type = 'S2'
            current_date = current_date
            current_date = current_date + dt.timedelta(days=1)
        shift_dict["end_date"] = current_date


    for i in list_of_shifts:
        print(i)
```

Expected output

```
{'shift_type': 'S1', 'start_date': datetime.date(2021, 4, 2), 
'end_date': datetime.date(2021, 4, 4)}
{'shift_type': 'S2', 'start_date': datetime.date(2021, 4, 10), 
'end_date': datetime.date(2021, 4, 21)}
{'shift_type': 'S1', 'start_date': datetime.date(2021, 4, 23), 
'end_date': datetime.date(2021, 4, 27)}
{'shift_type': 'S1', 'start_date': datetime.date(2021, 4, 29), 
'end_date': datetime.date(2021, 4, 29)}
```

Comment: `L` was not in the original question. This is a new parameter that has been introduced in the answer and bears no relevance to the original question...  otherwise one could keep adding letters with new meanings indefinitely.

Comment: Yes, sorry i don't know how to introduce a question here, in above your answer i just added a new list which i got randomly from API. With older list its working fine what if i got first parameter W first or L first

Comment: Just for that it gives error like `name 'shift_type' is not defined`

Comment: it is defined on line 6.  the indentation looks incorrect.